# Accessing type "properties" in C#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I'm using ROP (Railway Oriented Programming), modeling it after [swlaschin](https://github.com/swlaschin/Railway-Oriented-Programming-Example) in a SQLite wrapper:

And I am returning `RopResult` types:

```
type RopResult<'TSuccess, 'TMessage> =
    | Success of 'TSuccess * 'TMessage list
    | Failure of 'TMessage list
```

And all works fine in F# in composition, but I still need to interop to C# sometimes and in returning a `RopResult` things fall apart. ie:

```
RopResult<seq 't, DomainMessage>
```

How can I access those "properties" (ie. the C#'s ienumerable) without having to resort to casting it as a `dynamic`:

```
var ropResult = dao.All; //  RopResult<seq 't, DomainMessage>
var dyn = ropResult as dynamic;
foreach (SomeClass item in dyn.Item1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
}
```

Comment: You'd need to pattern match on the `RopResult` type, which C# can't do. I suppose your best bet is providing some "adapter" functions from F# that are C# friendlier than the actual discriminated union.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply cast to the relevant subtype or use pattern matching (in C# 7.0 or later):

```cs
switch (result)
{
    case RopResult<IEnumerable<T>, DomainMessage>.Success success:
        var value = success.Item1;
        var messages = success.Item2;
        // do something
        break;
    case RopResult<IEnumerable<T>, DomainMessage>.Failure failure:
        var errors = failure.Item;
        // do something else
        break;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

However, this isn't an ideal API from C#. You might want to write some extension methods to help with this. You might get [some inspiration from Chessie](http://fsprojects.github.io/Chessie/reference/chessie-errorhandling-csharp-resultextensions.html).